# Can pointer variable be declared in MIPS

Tags: mips32

In MIPS can we define pointer type variable in the .data directive and then initialize it with null?.... Í have to convert the following c code to MIPS assembly:

```
int main(){
       char str[256];
       int i = 0;
       char *result = NULL;
       scanf("%s",str)l;
       while(str[í] != '\0'){
            if(str[i] == 'm'){
                result = &str[i];
                break;
            }
            i++;
       }
       if(result != NULL)
           printf("Match at address %d\n", result);
       else
           printf("No match\n");
       return 0;
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can define a word and initialize it to 0, which is exactly the same thing anyway.

Comment: How would I check if the address is null?

Comment: The concept of a null pointer is a construct of the C language. You get to decide how you want to represent it in assembly language, with the understanding that it may prevent you from representing the full address space. (1) Decide how you want to represent a null address. (2) Compare against that value.

Comment: Is there any way in MIPS that, I can store an address in the memory and associate a label with that

Comment: @Tahlil `label: .word 0` in your data section, there is nothing special about addresses.